# AJAX - removing a row in MySQL from included AJAX PHP foreach

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 3 files. First index.php, where the logic happen. The next one is a file, where I read all MySQL rows and write it in PHP file, which is included using ajax and the content is printed into a div in index.php. Third file should be able to remove one specific row, after clicking on the specific class of the element. The element also has an id attribute, for jQuery to specify which one I would like to remove.

The removal isn't happening. It doesn't even write a console.log. Can you please look at it and tell me, where I made a mistake? It may be some "logical" error I can't see.

(It's a test project, I'm creating something like template for learning AJAX)

Parts to inspect from index.php:

```
        //this makes removing happen AJAX (NOT WORKING PART)
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.smazat').click(function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                console.log("Vyvoláno smazání záznamu: " + id + ".");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/smazatClanekAJAX.php',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function () {
                        console.log("Záznam smazán.");
                        vypsatNovinky();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```
//this function prints all the rows from db, 
//i use it on page load and if i insert new one, just for reloading the content
   function vypsatNovinky() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/vsechnyClankyAJAX.php", success: function (result) {
                    $("#vepsanyText").html(result);
                    console.log("Novinky z funkce vypsatNovinky() načteny.");
                }
            });
        }
```

vsechnyClankyAJAX.php

```
<?php
include "../db.php";
foreach ($database->queryAll("select * from clanky order by id desc") as $item) {
    echo "
    <hr>
    <strong>$item[title]</strong>
    <p>$item[text]</p>
    <p id='$item[id]' value='Smazat' class='smazat btn btn-danger'>Smazat</p>
    ";
}
exit;
```

smazatClanekAJAX.php - for removing

```
<?php
include('../db.php');
$database->query("delete from clanky where id='$_POST[id]'");
exit;
```

Comment: `$('.smazat').click()` binds a click handler to all elements with that class, that exist in the DOM _at that moment_. If you dynamically load and insert elements later, this won’t apply to them. The usual fix for this is called _event delegation_.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for your answer. I studied the jQuery DOCS

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution will be to use [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) of JQuery instead of [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and it will work.

Here you can check it in the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.smazat').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("Vyvoláno smazání záznamu: " + id + ".");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='1234' value='Smazat' class='smazat btn btn-danger'>Smazat</p>
```

Moreover

> $('.smazat').click()

binds a click handler to all elements with that class in the DOM, so you should not give the class name to any other element. [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Thank you for you example. I made the changes. But i don't understand. Why the "included" php foreach file make the script not working. Like there is no output in console

Comment: You can go to console and check for any error. Right click on your browser and select inspect element, check the value of ID, whether it's coming from database or not.